# How to style link inside embedded <object> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am loading a webpage in an object as such:

```
<object data="http://example.com"></object>
```

My requirement is to change the color of the links in this object. For that, I'm using the following piece of code

```
$('object').contents().find('a').css('color','#000');
```

It's not working as intended. Please review if there is a problem with my logic.

Comment: Does that page inside the object element happen to be from a different domain? Then you have no scripting access to its content, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: And where do you run this code? provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. In order to edit website within a frame, it has to be located on the same server as yours.